# Print Data Frame columns and modified types

Tags: python, r, postgresql, data.table, tidyverse

I have large tables both in length and width for data science. Frequently I want to move a data frame to a database `SQL` table. This means I have to write out each column type in my `create` statement. As columns grow > 200, it can be cumbersome to do this.

This seems like a good opportunity for a function. I think it would first check the column types in a data frame and return the appropriate `Postgres` column types, for me to copy and paste.

R -> PG12 Translation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-numeric.html

```
| R class      | PG12 datatype             | Note                                                                                                                 |
|--------------|---------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| factor, char | text                      | text can handle varying length strings                                                                               |
| integer      | smallint                  | if abs(x) <= 32767 then smallint                                                                                     |
| integer      | integer                   | if abs(x) <= 2147483647 then integer                                                                                 |
| integer      | bigint                    | if abs(x) <= 9223372036854775807 then bigint                                                                         |
| numeric      | smallint, integer, bigint | if there is nothing in the decimal places `4.0` coerce it to integer to save space                                   |
| numeric      | numeric(precision,scale)  | precision = nchar(unlist(strsplit(x = as.character(10.045), split = ".", fixed = T))[2]); scale = max(nchar(10.045)) |
| Date         | date                      |                                                                                                                      |
```

For example this table: `head(Orange)`
[image: code output]

would give these results:
[image: input code]

That I can copy and paste into a `create` statement:
[image: final result]

Are there any solutions for this that people have found or could someone help with the logic for this function? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: @akrun row 5 has multiple cases because it depends on the max size of the values in the numeric column. it could be any of those three see rows 2:4 for the documentation on the PostGres rules.

Comment: Did you try `dbWriteTable` with(out) `field.types` from [RPostgreSQL](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RPostgreSQL/RPostgreSQL.pdf)?

Answer (score 0):

No one has answered yet, so here's a functional (not optimal) solution I worked up.

```
x <- data.frame(smallint = 0:10, 
                smallint2 = 0.0:10.0,
                integer = 1e6:1.00001e6, 
                bigint1 = 1e11:1.0000000001e11, 
                bigint2 = 1e10:1.000000001e10, 
                bigint3 = 1e9:1.00000001e9, 
                bigint4 = 1e8:1.0000001e8, 
                text1 = LETTERS[1:11], 
                text2 = factor(LETTERS[1:11]), 
                date = as.Date("1985-01-21"),
                timestamp = Sys.time()
                , stringsAsFactors = F)

foo <- function(df){
        col.info <- sapply(X = df, FUN = function(z){RPostgreSQL::dbDataType(dbObj = con, obj = z)})
    print(data.frame(col = row.names(data.frame(col.info)), col.type = paste0(col.info,",")), row.names = F)
}
foo(df = x)
foo(df = Orange)
```